# Apache VirtualHost not loading correct certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, apache2

We are running into issues with this seemingly simple configuration on Apache 2.4. We can't seem to obtain the correct certificate while using the Virtual Host site2.net. We always get site1.net's certificate. Here's our `apacectl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:446                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server site1.net (/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/sites-enable/site1.conf:3)
         port 446 namevhost site1.net (/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/sites-enable/site1.conf:3)
         port 446 namevhost site2.net (/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/sites-enable/site2.conf:3)
*:444                  other.net (/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/sites-enable/other.conf:2)
```

Here's the VH configurations:

```
$ cat /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/sites-enable/site1.conf
<VirtualHost *:446>
    ServerName site1.net
    DocumentRoot /www/site1
    <Directory /www/site1>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/certs/site1.key
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/certs/site1.pem
</VirtualHost>

$ cat /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/sites-enable/site2.conf
<VirtualHost *:446>
    ServerName site2.net
    DocumentRoot "/www/site1/xyz"
    <Directory "/www/site1/xyz">
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/certs/site2.key
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/certs/site2.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The conf file `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` has not VirtualHost defined.
If we swap the certs and have the first Virtual Host loading the second certificate we see it correctly (i.e. there is no issue with the certificate itself).

We are testing with `openssl s_client -connect myip:446 -servername site2.net`

Why are we getting this strange behavior? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That appears to suggest that SNI is not working/used. That may be an issue in the Apache configuration, the openssl cli tool  and/or both. Does a different test, for example with `curl –resolve site2.net:446:myip https://site2.net:446/` show the same behaviour ?

Comment: Same behavior with curl, thanks!